# CSS Only - Dynamic Header Height & 100% Content Height with Scrollbars

Tags: html, css, web-applications, height, fullscreen

The goal is for the scrollbar not to be hidden with a dynamic height header.

There's a lot of posts on stackoverflow about CSS height 100%; My problem is kind of unique, so excuse if it's a dupe, but I couldn't find an answer.

So my web-app needs vertical scroll-bars + height 100%, and dynamic header height. Header has an unknown height, so the height of the content area should be 100%-header height.

The problem I couldn't figure out how to solve elegantly was that the Content vertical scroll-bars (especially bottom scroll-down button) would get hidden if you do a height:100% on it, with the header being up top. (height >100% is not ideal).

```
<style>
  html{
    height:100%;
  }
  body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  #header{
    background:blue;
  }
  #content{
    background:red;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:100%;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id='header'>
    dynamic height top. (Text here could be any length.)
  </div>
  <div id='content'>
    100% with no-hidden scroll-down scrollbar button.
  </div>
</body>
```

Could this be done with No JavaScript and No HTML/CSS Tables? (I had colspan issues using css tables, and it seems bad practice to use html tables for layout)

Wonder if a CSS/HTML guru out there has an answer.

http://jsbin.com/ijoqe4/ <-- see the hidden bottom scroll button here

http://jsbin.com/ijoqe4/edit <-- edit in jsbin

Thanks for any insight. :)

Comment: What's wrong with tables? They're valid HTML and they fix your problem quite easily without any complicated hacks.

Comment: I'm extremely confused. The exmaples you posted seem to give you *exactly* what you have described that you want. Can you please state the differences between your current attempt and the desired effect?

Comment: @Thomas, well actually I tried doing it with Tables too, and it didn't work.

Comment: @Xixonia, what I'm trying to do is make it so the bottom scroll-down button on the scrollbar doesn't get covered... in Chrome&Firefox, if you do height 100% on the Bottom, with a Dynamic Header Height for the top, the bottom scroll button (and a good chunk of the scrollbar, depending on the height of the Top-Header) gets hidden, so I was wondering if there was a purely CSS way to do it, while still showing all of the scroll-bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a dynamic header, as far as I know, there is no way to do this in pure CSS. Your problem arises from the fact that you:

- Want the header to be dynamic, therefore the container must be dynamic accordingly
- To have the position of the container adapt dynamically according to the header, you need a `block`-level header, with a `block`-level container beneath it.
- The only way to have the container stretch to the bottom of the window is to set `position: absolute; top:0; bottom: 0;`, with `bottom` referring to the bottom of the window. But you need `top` to refer to the bottom of the head, not the top of the window (which is the element `bottom` is referring to).

So, since it isn't possible in pure CSS to have an element adjusted in position with regard to two different other elements, you'll either have to make use of a javascript solution, or use tables. Sad, but true.

But, even though tables for design is normally seen as a taboo, in this case it would be your best and cleanest option, and it is still - technically - only HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Herman, had to read it a few times to get it... it's always the simplest things that seems to be the most confusing, hah.  I will bite the bullet and use JavaScript... (I couldn't even get the scrollbars to act right using css tables nor reg tables http://jsbin.com/ijoqe4/8/edit) JavaScript seems like the best bet.

Comment: Herman: I think your message is correct, but your 3rd point (if I understand you correctly) is not entirely—you can make an element have 100% height without using position:absolute: `html, body, #content { height:100%; }` will cause the #content element to be 100% of the window's height: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/hLbyE/ The caveat is that all parent element(s) up the DOM tree must have an explicite height.

Comment: @jacob Indeed you are right, and doing what you suggest is a common solution for making sticky footers and headers. Thinking about it now, there might be a way to do this afterall, with 100% height and negative margins (percentage-based, as well?), but I'm not sure how "dynamic" such a solution will be in any case, if it works. Worth trying though!

Comment: @HermanSchaaf mm, that (percentage-based margin equal to percetage-based height of header/footer) would be a little more dynamic, but alas, won't get the ultimate effect people will want (where the margin actually adjusts to content forcing the header's/footer's height to grow). Why is this so bloody difficult :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe try setting your html, body height to 98% rather than 100%. You have disabled your body overflow, so the div using 100% is going beyond the browser size.

Comment: Hi robx, thanks for the reply. Yeah, that's one option... but the OCD in me can't stand to waste those precious pixels... (the ones that are between the end of the Bottom/Center Div and bottom of the viewport) :/ and The height of people's status bars might be different, as well as the dynamic height of the top...